# Why does Popen's poll function wait forever when exit code is 0?

Tags: python, subprocess

Take this first script `slave.py`:

```
import sys
print('hello')
sys.exit(0)
```

I am calling it from another script, waiting for it to end:

```
import shlex
import subprocess
import time

p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('python ./slave.py'))
while True:
  if p.poll():
    break
  time.sleep(1)
print('done')
```

This loop runs forever -- the master endlessly waits for `poll` to be something else than `None`.

However, if the exit code of the slave is set to `1`, then `poll` returns something meaningfull -- as expected really.

Am I doing something or is there something I do not understand about `poll`? I am using python 3.6.6.

Comment: If you run the code `if 0: print('foo')`, would you expect it to print anything?

Comment: `if p.poll() is not None:` suddenly looks like a better idea now, doesn't it. Thanks.